# SmartTarget Filtering and Ordering "Add a content filter" button is disabled

Tags: smarttarget

We are trying to create a Promotion in SmartTarget 2014 SP1 and have configured "Where" and "When", but ran into a dilemma with "What".  In the Filtering and Ordering pane, the Content Filtering button is disabled.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: SmartTarget Content Filtering button disabled]

We've been clicking around various options thinking that there is a dependency on the Where/When selections or the Content Selection, but that hasn't helped.

We've also read the documentation here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-09B2E4B8-AA87-4B45-9EF8-FBC85C0BA16E.  However, it doesn't mention anything about why this button would be disabled.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen this scenario in a new SmartTarget/Fredhopper install when you have not enabled any live attributes (= things that you can use to filter on) in the Fredhopper Business Manager.

Its a little bit hidden away, but described [here in the docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-EA86B8AA-6904-40AD-AF3A-AA7BC0ED1CD0).

Note that while republishing content will usually 'enable' the button, my filters never actually worked until a full reindex was done, which is a [bit of a pain in the backside](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-1C66ABA4-2CDD-47DE-BEDC-75C674A7F367) especially on a production environment where you don't have any access to the servers.